# how to use paramiko to execute remote commands

Tags: python

I wanted to compress a folder on a remote namchine.For that i am using paramiko.
But i don't know how to do that using paramiko.
Any suggestions??

This is my code:

```
dpath = '/var/mysql/5.1/mysql.zip'    
port = 22    
host = '10.88.36.7'    
transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))    
transport.connect(username=suser, password=spass)    
channel = transport.open_channel(kind="session")    
channel.exec_command('zip -r /var/db/mysql /var/db/mysql')    
transport.close()
```

whats wrong in this??

Comment: What do you have so far, and how doesn't it work?

Comment: If you are doing something more elaborate than just this one command, it'd be worthwhile to look into using Fabric <http://docs.fabfile.org/>. It's built on top of paramiko and hides much of this boilerplate code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After

```
channel.exec_command(...)
```

You have to wait the termination of the command with:

```
while not channel.exit_status_ready()
    ... wait ... ( you can read the output with channel.recv, or sleep a bit)
```

Furthermore, you're zip command is weird... don't you want to say

```
zip -r /var/db/mysql.zip /var/db/mysql
```